# How to get the weekly, monthly and yearly sales using where statements

Tags: java, sql, where-clause

Hi i already get the daily sales. now i want to get the weekly, monthly and yearly sales and already tried the weekly sales but the problem is the monthly sales is the one being selected

```
public void weekly(){
         
          DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        String date = dtf.format(now);
         
            try{
           con = Connector.getConnection();
            java.sql.Statement st = con.createStatement();
            String query = "SELECT sum(Quantity) FROM `salesproduct_table` WHERE Date = WEEK(CURDATE())";
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            
            if(rs.next()){
                
                productsales4.setText(rs.getString(1));
                
            }
            
            
            }catch(Exception ex){
                
            }
```

tried already different kind of syntax but i cant fix it

Comment: Define "weekly".

Answer (score 0):

For month:

```
String query = "SELECT sum(Quantity) FROM `salesproduct_table` WHERE MONTH(Date) = MONTH(CURDATE())";
```

for year:

```
String query = "SELECT sum(Quantity) FROM `salesproduct_table` WHERE YEAR(Date) = YEAR(CURDATE())";
```

Comment: Hi how in weekly sir? TIA

Comment: String query = "SELECT sum(Quantity) FROM `salesproduct_table` WHERE WEEK(Date) = WEEK(CURDATE())"; NOTE: this only works for the current year so be wary